# iOS Navigation Bar Title View Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

In iOS 7+, how would one go about setting the navigation bar title view to be a stack of actions that trigger sorting a mutable array within the view controller?

For instance:
Yik Yak's Navigation Bar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcJNM.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the navigation bar title to be a UIView with `self.navigationItem.titleView`. For example:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"New", @"Hot"]];
[segmentedControl sizeToFit];
// Configure your segmentedControl to your liking...

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

Also, can take a look at this one: [UINavigationBar with buttons as title.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676368/uinavigationbar-with-buttons-as-title) Basically, you can customize the titleView as much as you want.